# What is the derivative of $f(x) = 5\cos(1.2x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of the function $f(x) = 5\cos(1.2x)$?  I am having a ton of trouble with these derivatives.  I have no clue where to start.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = 5\cos(1.2x)$

Use the chain rule.  Recall that $\cos(1.2x)$ is a composite function $g(u(x))$ where $u(x) = 1.2x$ and $g(u) = \cos(u)$.  The chain rule says that $\frac{d}{dx}g(u(x)) = g'(u(x)) \cdot u'(x)$.

$f'(x) = 5\frac{d}{dx}\cos(1.2x) = -5 \cdot 1.2 \cdot\sin(1.2x) = -6\sin(1.2x)$

Answer (score 3):

(All derivatives here are with respect to $x$.) Work from the outside in, using the chain rule as needed. You know that if $a$ is a constant and $u$ is a function of $x$, $[au]'=au'$, so $$[5\cos 1.2x]'=5[\cos 1.2x]'\;.$$ Now you have to differentiate $\cos 1.2x$. At the outermost level this is a cosine of something. The derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$, so with the chain rule you have $$[\cos 1.2x]'=(-\sin 1.2x)[1.2x]'\;.$$ Finally, $[1.2x]'=1.2$. Now put the pieces together:

$$[5\cos 1.2x]'=5[\cos 1.2x]'=5(-\sin 1.2x)[1.2x]'=5(-\sin 1.2x)(1.2)=-6\sin 1.2x\;.$$

With a bit of practice you’ll be able to do all of that in just one or two steps, but when you’re just getting started, it doesn’t hurt to take it a step at a time.